# Asterisks in tables

Tags: tables

What are these black rectangles (they are not in minimal code but in origin file) and why are asterisks not by numbers?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\setlength\textwidth{145mm}
\setlength\textheight{247mm}
\setlength\oddsidemargin{15mm}
\setlength\evensidemargin{15mm}
\setlength\topmargin{0mm}
\setlength\headsep{0mm}
\setlength\headheight{0mm}
\let\openright=\clearpage
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell,amsmath, graphicx}
\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}
\newcommand\stack[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack{#1}}}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[htb]

        \caption{Příklady zjištěných parametrů II}
        \small\centering
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} 
                c
                S[table-format=2.2(2)]
                S[table-format=2.2(2)]
                S[table-format=6.0(1)]
                S[table-format=6.0(3)]
                S[table-format=1.4(2)]
                S[table-format=1.3(3)] 
            }\Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}
            &&&&&&\\[-10pt]
            \shortstack{Číslo\\ zdroje}
            &   \stack{$a$\\ ($\mathrm{M}_{\odot}$)}
            &   \stack{$i$\\ ($\si{\degree}$)}
            &   \stack{$T_1$\\ ($\mathrm{K}$)}
            &   \stack{$T_2$\\ ($\mathrm{K}$)}
            &   \stack{$\Omega_1$\\ ($\si{\degree}$)}
            &   \stack{$\Omega_2$\\ ($\si{\degree}$)}   \\\midrule                                      
            7 & 43,9(3)     & 81,0(11)          &  30000$^*$    &   19380(520)    &  3,534(55)         &  5,615(84)   \\
            8 & 44,2(3)     & 67,6(4)           &  30000$^*$    &     24000$^\ast$  &  3,156$^\ast$       &   4,008(81)    \\
            9 & 44,0(3)     & 73,6(3)           &   30000$^*$       &   24000$^\ast$&   3,328(34)           &   5,065$^\ast$  \\
            \Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}
        \end{tabular*}

    \smallskip
    \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\textit{Pozn:}
    Čísla v závorkách jsou chyby posledních uvedených cifer. $^*$značí fixované 
    parametry.}

    \end{table} 



\begin{table}[htb]   
 \caption{Příklady zjištěných parametrů II} 
    \small\centering
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}  
            c
            S[table-format=1.4(1)]
            S[table-format=2.0]
            S[table-format=2.2]
            S[table-format=2.1(1)]
            S[table-format=1.1(1)]
            S[table-format=2.4(1)] 
        }\Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}
        &&&&&&\\[-10pt]
        \shortstack{Číslo\\ zdroje}
        &   \stack{$q = \dfrac{M_2}{M_1}$}
        &   \stack{$M_1$\\ ($\mathrm{M}_{\odot}$)}
        &   \stack{$M_2$ \\ ($\mathrm{M}_{\odot}$)}
        &   \stack{$R_1$\\ ($\mathrm{R}_{\odot}$)}
        &   \stack{$R_2$\\ ($\mathrm{R}_{\odot}$)}
        &   \stack{$V_{\gamma}$\\ (\si{\kilo\meter\per\second})}    \\\midrule
        4 &         &                           &                       &           &               &   21,7(5)     \\
        7 & 0,3821      &   25$^\ast$       &   9,55            &   14,3        &   4,0             & 21,74(50)\\
        8 & 0,4147      &   25$^\ast$      &    10,4            &   16,8        &   7,0          &     21,77(51) \\
        9 & 0,3962      &   25$^\ast$      &    9,91           &    15,6           & 4,8          &     21,74(50)          \\

        \Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}
    \end{tabular*}

\smallskip
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\textit{Pozn:}
Čísla v závorkách jsou chyby posledních uvedených cifer. $^*$značí fixované 
parametry.}    
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\setlength\textwidth{145mm}
\setlength\textheight{247mm}
\setlength\oddsidemargin{15mm}
\setlength\evensidemargin{15mm}
\setlength\topmargin{0mm}
\setlength\headsep{0mm}
\setlength\headheight{0mm}
\let\openright=\clearpage

\usepackage{booktabs, makecell,amsmath, graphicx}
\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}

\NewDocumentCommand{\anote}{}{\makebox[0pt][l]{$^*$}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
\caption{Příklady zjištěných parametrů I}
    \small
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} 
                            c
                            S[table-format=1.6(2)]
                            S[table-format=5.3(3)]
                            S[table-format=1.4(3)]
                            S[table-format=3.1(2)]
                            S[table-format=3.2(2)]
                            S[table-format=3.1(2)]
                            }
\Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}
&&&&&&\\[-10pt]
\makecell[t]{Číslo\\ zdroje}
    &   {\makecell[t]{$P$\\ (dny)}}
        &   {\makecell[t]{$T_0$\\ (RJD)}}
            &   {\makecell[t]{$e$}}
                &   {\makecell[t]{$\omega$\\ (\si{\degree})}}
                    &   {\makecell[t]{$K_1$\\ (\si{\kilo\meter\per\second})}}
                        &   {\makecell[t]{$K_2$\\ (\si{\kilo\meter\per\second})}}   \\
    \midrule
1 & 5,732436(15) & 54002,780(46)  & 0,0910(37) & 149,2(30) &   &            \\
2 & 5,732436(3)  & 54002,7241(96) & 0,0858(41) & 145,6(39) &   &            \\
3 & 5,732436(1)  & 54002,7775(34) & 0,0883(26) & 149,1(23) &   &            \\
4 &             &   54002,705(60)   &   0,0955(69)      & 144,0(39)     &   106,33(71)  & \\
5 &             &   54002,785       &                   &149,2          &   108,5           &       \\
6 &             &   54002,768       &                   &148,3          &   107,9           &       \\
7 &             &                   &                   &148,7(24)          &               &       \\
8 &             &                   &                   &144,2(21)          &               &       \\
9 &             &                   &                   &140,0(18)          &               &       \\
11 &5,732436\anote      &56295,674(62)  &0,1133(3)      &141,3(2)               &   &                \\
\hline
12 & 5,732436\anote & 57040,938\anote   & 0,1124\anote & 144,2\anote    &104,6(16)&266(20)\\
13 & 5,732436\anote             &                   &   0,1124(92)          &   141,2119(81)            &           & \\
14 & 5,732436\anote             &                   &   0,1124          &   141,43 (75)         &           & \\
15& 5,732436\anote              &                   &   0,1130(71)          &   141,0834(48)            &           & \\
\Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}
    \multicolumn{7}{l}{\footnotesize \textit{Pozn:}
Čísla v~závorkách jsou chyby posledních uvedených cifer.}
\end{tabular*}
\label{parametryI}
    \end{table}  

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Do you mean [this Asterix](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/pt/thumb/0/01/Asterix.jpg/250px-Asterix.jpg) :P (sorry, bad joke). In your document you probably have the `draft` option, which makes the black squares appear. The black boxes appear because you have lots of `Overfull \hbox`es in your table.

Comment: consider using the threeparttable package to make table notes, this works well with siunitx. You get the black boxes because the * makes the cell wider than you have specified.

Comment: Thank you and how to specify format with asterisks? Should I add a number to brakets or behind the comma?

Comment: see my answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/462116/tables-spaces-between-lines/462143#462143 ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never use `\shortstack`. It doesn't do what you're expecting it to. Use `\makecell` instead, in tables.

It makes sense to make the asterisk zero width, but you should also be more careful about the number of digits in `table-format`.

With `table-align-text-post=false`, the asterisk will be attached to the number.

Ensure to brace items in the header of S-columns.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\setlength\textwidth{145mm}
\setlength\textheight{247mm}
\setlength\oddsidemargin{15mm}
\setlength\evensidemargin{15mm}
\setlength\topmargin{0mm}
\setlength\headsep{0mm}
\setlength\headheight{0mm}
\let\openright=\clearpage

\usepackage{booktabs, makecell,amsmath, graphicx}
\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}

\NewDocumentCommand{\anote}{}{\makebox[0pt][l]{$^*$}}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[htb]

\caption{Příklady zjištěných parametrů II}
\small\centering

\sisetup{table-align-text-post=false}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} 
  c
  S[table-format=2.2(2)]
  S[table-format=2.2(2)]
  S[table-format=6.0]
  S[table-format=6.0(3)]
  S[table-format=1.3(2)]
  S[table-format=1.3(2)]
}
\toprule
\makecell{Číslo\\ zdroje}
  &   {\makecell{$a$\\ ($\mathrm{M}_{\odot}$)}}
  &   {\makecell{$i$ \\ (\si{\degree})}}
  &   {\makecell{$T_1$\\ (\si{\kelvin})}}
  &   {\makecell{$T_2$\\ (\si{\kelvin})}}
  &   {\makecell{$\Omega_1$\\ (\si{\degree})}}
  &   {\makecell{$\Omega_2$\\ (\si{\degree})}} \\
\midrule
7 & 43,9(3) & 81,0(11) & 30000\anote & 19380(520)   & 3,534(55)   & 5,615(84) \\
8 & 44,2(3) & 67,6(4)  & 30000\anote & 24000\anote  & 3,156\anote & 4,008(81) \\
9 & 44,0(3) & 73,6(3)  & 30000\anote & 24000\anote  & 3,328(34)   & 5,065\anote \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\smallskip
\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\footnotesize
  \textit{Pozn:}
  Čísla v závorkách jsou chyby posledních uvedených cifer.
  $^*$~značí fixované parametry.
}

\end{table} 



\begin{table}[htb]   

\caption{Příklady zjištěných parametrů II} 

\small\centering

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}  
  c
  S[table-format=1.4]
  S[table-format=2.0]
  S[table-format=2.2]
  S[table-format=2.1]
  S[table-format=1.1]
  S[table-format=2.2(2)] 
}
\toprule
\makecell{Číslo\\ zdroje}
&   {\makecell{$q = \dfrac{M_2}{M_1}$}}
&   {\makecell{$M_1$\\ ($\mathrm{M}_{\odot}$)}}
&   {\makecell{$M_2$ \\ ($\mathrm{M}_{\odot}$)}}
&   {\makecell{$R_1$\\ ($\mathrm{R}_{\odot}$)}}
&   {\makecell{$R_2$\\ ($\mathrm{R}_{\odot}$)}}
&   {\makecell{$V_{\gamma}$\\ (\si{\kilo\meter\per\second})}} \\
\midrule
4 &        &        &       &      &     & 21,7(5)     \\
7 & 0,3821 & 25\anote &  9,55 & 14,3 & 4,0 & 21,74(50) \\
8 & 0,4147 & 25\anote & 10,4  & 16,8 & 7,0 & 21,77(51) \\
9 & 0,3962 & 25\anote &  9,91 & 15,6 & 4,8 & 21,74(50) \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\smallskip
\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\footnotesize
  \textit{Pozn:}
  Čísla v závorkách jsou chyby posledních uvedených cifer.
  $^*$ značí fixované parametry.}    

\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, but I don't understand very well. I tried another table (I added it in my question). Where do I mistake plese?

Comment: @Elisabeth You forgot `\sisetup{table-align-text-post=false}`; the third column should have a specification `5.4(2)`; the fourth `1.4(2)`; the fifth `3.4(2)`; the last `3.0(2)`. You should not use `\Xhline` and the silly empty row with negative spacing; `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` are much better. The thickness can be changed, see the `booktabs` manual, but be careful as very thick black rules remind obituaries.